# Updating Progressbar based on listviewitem-focus

Tags: c#, .net, listview

I'm trying to make my progressBar update according to the current amount of values in one of the `SubItems` columns.

Image for Reference:

Here I'm giving player Joel 4 jump numbers. (Everything works as expected)
[image]

However, after creating another player and giving him jumps (works as well). I want the progressBar to update according to whomever i've selected.

If i then try to re-select a player, and add jumps to him again, the progressBar doesn't realize it's on that player.

**Current Code:**

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
         progress(); // function that updates the progressBar
}
```

If no rows are selected, don't run the function.

**Progress-function-snippet:**

```
public void progress()
{
     if ((listView1.SelectedItems[0].SubItems[3].Text.Split(',').Length - 1) == 4)
           progressBar1.Value = 80;
...
...
...
}
```

I'm calculating the amount of "**,**" signs there is, and updating the progressBar according to that.

TL;DR: Updating progressBar according to which row is **selected** based on the amount of "**,**" that SubItem contains. (eg. 2 = 40%, 3 = 60%)

Comment: As you swap players, you need to have the number of jumps recorded and reset it to that player surely?

Comment: @BugFinder The strange part is that, the progressbar should update as soon as a row is selected and run the progress-function. (listview_selectedIndexChanged)

Comment: when you repopulate the listview, it doesnt sound like the selected index changes - try doing so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason after of hours of trying. The problem was that a blank-space was generated first of all before any jumps where added, once i formated the jump-string, everything works.

This was in fact the correct solution all along, the problem lied elsewhere:

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count != 0)
      progress();
}
```